# Can't clean format in TWRP Recovery

Tags: cyanogenmod, moto-x, formatting

Phone Moto X, "Ghost" 2013, 1st-gen., Developer's version and unlocked with Motorola code.

Maybe this is not supposed to be cleaned off, but thought I'd ask as I am far from an expert with this stuff. I am moving up from CyanogenMod cm12 to cm13 and it is strongly suggested to clean before an install up to the next level.

Using TWRP "wipe" and selecting everything, I get this error...

```
Formatting USB OTG using mkdosfs...
process ended with ERROR=1
unable to wipe '/usb-otg'.
unknown MTP message type: 1
unable to wipe '/usb-otg'.
```

I searched online and found a Fastboot command using '$ fastboot format userdata' on a Ubuntu PC (with ADB) that returned the same error after completing the format.

How can I get a complete clean system to start with?

Comment: In this case, meaning "clean" flashing a ROM, what is meant is you wipe all user and system data... not everything (this could cause a potential hard brick situation in rare cases). You would open TWRP and go to Wipes and Advanced and select caches, boot, system, and (user)data, that is all that is needed for a "clean" install. USB-OTG shouldn't be cleaned, that is an external device. Wiping additional stuff, like EFS, internal storage (where your rom/gapps likely are), or recovery, could potentially be disastrous.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it is a virus-type issue. I just installed a fresh copy of cm13 and opened the PlayStore and the only app in my list showed App Ops which was supposed to be a permissions manager. But every time I uninstall it it re-installs itself. I am now thinking that the usb-otg partition is encrypted. This makes me even more determined to clear that /usb-otg partition.

Comment: USB-OTG is an EXTERNAL device partition connected via USB like a thumb drive or external hard drive... do you have any external storage device connected to the device? Unless it's a simple thumb drive connected via an usb-otg cable, I sure wouldn't format it.